# Obtaining parent directories in Java's File API

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems

**Note**: I am only interested in "pure JRE" solutions here: that is, solutions involving the types that ship with the JRE (and, most likely, live inside the `java.io` package). I'm **sure** Apache Commons, etc. offers utility classes that do this nicely from a single method call, but I need pure JRE here.

I have the following runtime directory structure:

```
MyProject/
    fizz.txt
    src/
        com/
            myorg/
                Driver
```

My `Driver` is an entry point (contains a static `main` method) and I will actually be invoking it from the command-line separate from the rest of my project's build/deployment, etc:

```
java com.myorg.Driver -url blah.example.com
```

etc.

Inside `Driver`, I need to read `fizz.txt` and do stuff with it. Note: `fizz.txt` will **always** be located 3 parent directories above `Driver`, no matter what.

Inside `Driver` I have the following code:

```
File fizz = new File("../../../fizz.txt");
System.out.println("fizz = " + fizz.getAbsolutePath());
```

When I run `Driver`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../../fizz.txt not found.
    at com.myorg.Driver(Driver.java:76)
    at com.myorg.Driver.main(Driver.java:45)
fizz = /home/myuser/relay/workbench/eclipse-juno/workspace/MyProject/../../../
```

It seems that Java is not honoring the concept of "`..`" as the relation "*parent-of*". So I ask: how do I use the File API (**again, pure JRE**) to access `fizz.txt` from `Driver`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java *is* honoring the concept of ".." as the relation "parent-of". The problem is, it is using current working directory as a reference, not the directory where your class is located.

If you want to put the file together with your classes tree, you may consider calling `getClass().getResourceAsStream("file name")` method to access it. Then your code will not depend on the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

`File` references are contextual from the point of execution of Java, not your class...

As far as Java is concerned, you execution context will be `MyProject`, meaning you should try using `new File("fizz.txt")` instead